# Problema em programação C - Vetores

Tags: c, array

O problema é:

> Escrever um algoritmo que lê 3 vetores `A[1..10], B[1.10] e C[1..10]`
>   e escreve os elementos que estão em A e B (interseção) mas não estão
>   em C. Escreva os valores na ordem em que eles aparecem no vetor A. Os
>   três vetores devem ser lidos separadamente (em primeiro lugar, todo o
>   vetor A, após, o vetor B e por fim o vetor C).

Minha solução (que não está rodando):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  int A[10], B[10], C[10], i, j, k;
  for (i=0; i<=9; i++) 
    scanf ("%d",&A[i]);
  for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
    scanf ("%d",&B[j]);
  for (k=0; k<=9; k++) 
  scanf ("%d",&C[k]);

  for (i=0; i<=9; i++) 
    {
      for (j=0; j<=9; j++) 
        {
          if (A[i]==B[j]) 
            {
              for (k=0; k<=9; k++) 
                {
                  if (A[i]!=C[k]) 
                    printf ("%d\n",C[k]);
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Onde está o erro e como posso corrigir?

Answer (score 1):

Você está lendo os 3 vetores corretamente, e comparando os vetores A e B corretamente e na ordem do A. O problema é o terceiro loop, quando você busca o conteúdo de C.

Aqui, você está imprimindo todos em C que estão diferentes do elemento em A sendo comparado, na verdade você precisa verificar se algum em C é igual ao elemento de A sendo verificado, e caso não tenha nenhum imprimir.

O loop acho que pode ficar assim:

```
// dentro do if (A[i] == B[j]) {
int repetidos = 0;
for(int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
  // se repetir, incrementa
  if (A[i] == C[k]) {
    repetidos++;
  }
}
// sem repetidos? então imprime
if (repetidos == 0) {
  printf("%d\n", A[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ainda não deu certo, mas, já ajudou! Obrigado!

Comment: tinha que tirar o `if` dentro do loop... editei a resposta